# How to update records of 'ProfilePasswordPolicy' using SOAP API in POSTMAN?

Tags: soap-api, metadata-api, postman

I want to know how we can update records of the ProfilePasswordPolicy object using Postman.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profilepasswordpolicy.htm

If I can get an example request body, URL, and headers then it will be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Field:
SecuritySettings

Body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <soapenv:Header>
    <tns:SessionHeader>
        <tns:sessionId>token</tns:sessionId>
    </tns:SessionHeader>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <updateMetadata xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
        <metadata xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="SecuritySettings">
        <passwordPolicies>
            <obscureSecretAnswer>false</obscureSecretAnswer>
            <maxLoginAttempts>TenAttempts</maxLoginAttempts>
        </passwordPolicies>
        </metadata>
        </updateMetadata>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Headers:

```
Content-Type:text/xml
charset:UTF-8
SOAPAction:login
Accept:text/xml
```